# How to allocate memory to a string array in C - malloc error

Tags: c, malloc, runtime-error

Problem:
  I want to allocate memory to the elements of a fixed sized string array, however, I experience a crash 75% of the time.

That is 25% of the time my program runs flawlessly, but the error is one I have not experienced before

```
#define PACKAGE_COUNT 60
#define MAX_COUNT     5

const char *colors[] = { "blue", "red", "yellow", "purple", "orange" };

char **generatePackage() {


  char **generatedPackage = malloc(PACKAGE_COUNT);
  int randomIndex         = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i <= PACKAGE_COUNT; ++i) {

    randomIndex         = rand() / (RAND_MAX / MAX_COUNT + 1);
    generatedPackage[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeof(colors[randomIndex])); 
    // ERROR

    strcpy((generatedPackage[i]), colors[randomIndex]);

    // printf("generatePackage - %d: %s \n", i + 1, generatedPackage[i]);
  }

  return generatedPackage;
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your for loop counts the array entries from 1 to PACKAGE_COUNT but they are indexed between 0 and (PACKAGE_COUNT-1) as is the case with all arrays in C. Changing ++i (which adds one to i and then uses the result) to (i++) which uses your result then increments i will resolve this.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeof(colors[randomIndex]))` should be `malloc(strlen(colors[randomIndex]) + 1)`. Additionally, you need to allocate space for the pointers, as @xing points out

Comment: Please don't post images of text — post the text.  That's unreadable on a mobile device (actually, it's also unreadable on a full-size browser on a Mac, too).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler noted, the images were there to assist to show the location of the error on the IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not take into account the fact that the size of a pointer is not one. Hence, only a fraction of the size was allocated. Thus, some pointers had not enough memory to be allocated, causing the program to crash only when accessing one of those.

```
#define PACKAGE_COUNT 60
#define MAX_COUNT     5

const char *colors[] = { "blue", "red", "yellow", "purple", "orange" };

char **generatePackage() {
  char **generatedPackage = malloc(PACKAGE_COUNT * sizeof(char*)); // The size of a pointer is not one, so this a multiplicative factor must be applied
  int randomIndex         = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < PACKAGE_COUNT; ++i) { // the upper bound is i < PACKAGE_COUNT, not i <= PACKAGE_COUNT

    randomIndex         = rand() / (RAND_MAX / MAX_COUNT + 1);
    generatedPackage[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(colors[randomIndex]) + 1)); // You probably want to allocate enough space for the string, rather than enough space for the pointer, so you must use strlen

    strcpy((generatedPackage[i]), colors[randomIndex]);

    // printf("generatePackage - %d: %s \n", i + 1, generatedPackage[i]);
  }

  return generatedPackage;
}
```